# content information of all cms pages is not shown

Tags: magento-1.9, cms-pages, page-content

What do i have to do in order to get the content information of my cms pages to be displayed. Maybe a screenshot could show the problem a bit better:

[image]

Comment: Any error on console? Try to flush the cache and reload the page again.

Comment: did it, nothing happened